# Running all test classes in all projects

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have the following project setup:

[image]

The application consists of several projects where each project have a test package. These test packages contain the test classes for this particular project and also a `TestAll class` which runs all tests in this package. The TestAll class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( {
    TestClass1.class,
    TestClass2.class,
    TestClassX.class

} )
public class TestAll {}
```

Would it be possible to run all these `TestAll classes`, in all projects at once? Right now I am manually running each `TestAll class` which is very timeconsuming. Preferly I would like the result to be saved somewhere but that is a later problem

Comment: Are we talking about Eclipse here?

Comment: Yeah, im running eclipse

Comment: I really think you should look at either [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) or similar project/build management tools. It would help you a lot! You would build and test everything with a simple command.

Comment: Is it necessary to run inside the Eclipse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by the hints given here: [Run Junit-Tests from several projects conveniently fast in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137479/run-junit-tests-from-several-projects-conveniently-fast-in-eclipse)

What I did was to create a new project, `TestAllProjects`, and added all the projects containing my tests in build path -> project

When this was done I created a `TestAllClass` in this project:

```
import path.to.package.containg.test.for.project1.testAll.*;
import path.to.package.containg.test.for.project2.testAll.*;
import path.to.package.containg.test.for.projectX.testAll.*;


@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( {
    TestAllProject1.class, //Refrence to a TestAll class
    TestAllProject2.class, //Refrence to a TestAll class
    TestAllProjectX.class  //Refrence to a TestAll class

} )

public class TestAllProjects {}
```

Now when I run this, it will run all the TestAll classes i've created in each project, resulting in that all test classes are beeing run