# how to exclude a folder (containing eclipse projects) during import of existing projects into workspace in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to exclude a folder(containing certain eclipse projects) during import of "Existing projects into workspace".

During the import I am specifying the root directory which contains 100's of sub-folders . In this regard -> I want to eclipse to skip import of projects from certain sub-folders.

> p.s: i am looking something similar to .gitignore file :-)

Will be happy, if someone can suggest me a solution here.

Thanks !!

Comment: maybe you can get an idea in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187868/how-can-i-exclude-some-folders-from-my-eclipse-project). Hope you help.

Comment: You can explicitly check out required projects in eclipse. So in this way you will ignore other projects.

Comment: In my case, I have different workspaces -> I just need to import the folder containing eclipse projects into each workspace.

Comment: You could create an Oomph setup and and let it handle all project imports. It allows you to declare filters based on project names, location etc.. Otherwise I've searched quite a bit for a solution using import wizards but never found anything. I think [Bug 562798](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562798) might be of interest. It's not exactly the same issue but depending on how it will be implemented (if it will at all) we might be able to ignore certain projects.