# Can I access remote files on a different OS from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, remote-server

I remember i could remotely open files that are on my server via Notepad++. Can I do that with Eclipse so that I can edit files on my computer and when I save it saves on that file directly on the server.

I am using Windows 7 and my server is CentOS (I think).

Comment: What OS's are on your computer and the server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Remote Systems Explorer lets you do this. Open "Help > Install new software...", select the "Galileo Update Site", find the Remote Systems Explorer and install it.

Once you've got it installed, open the "Remote Systems" view and add a connection to your favourite server. I use it all the time; works like a charm.

Comment: Both answers helped but i will mark this one as accepted answer because of "open the "Remote Systems" view" :D I tryed everything but this... Now i opened that i managed to get it to work as you can see in link below... :)

http://www.arvag.net/

Comment: The best thing is that when you re-open eclipse, it takes you right to the directory that you were working in when you last closed. For UTF-8, right click on any file or folder and select properties. In the info tab, change file encoding to "UTF-8". It gets applied to all files and folders for that connection.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse normally needs files to be in a project, but if you are able to map the network drive, you can add the remote folder into a project as a linked resource, then it can be modified as if it is on the local machine (except for additional latency).

To maintain portability, you can specify a [path variable](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-13.htm) for the remote file system and define a relative path from that variable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130400/eclipse-classpath-entries-only-used-for-tests/1130437#1130437) for details of setting up linked resources.

If mapping the drive is not an option, there is the [Remote System Explorer architecture](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rse.doc.isv/guide/tutorial/popup.html). I've not used it myself so I can't say how well it works, but this blog describes how to [use RSE to browse remote files](http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/).