# External output folder in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to make the project's output folder an external folder, instead of a folder located under the project root?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, you can define it as a **linked folder**.

[image: http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-2.1-200303272130/images/linked-resource.gif]

This this [SO answer for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300328/eclipse-attach-source-javadoc-to-a-library-via-a-local-property) (or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130400/eclipse-classpath-entries-only-used-for-tests/1130437#1130437))

> To create a new linked folder select **`New->Folder`**, input bin in the folder name: field then click **`Advanced>>`**
>
> Click **`Link to folder`** in the file system
>   Click on **`Variables`**... to bring up the Select Path Variable dialog.
>
> If this is your first time, or you are linking to a new location select New... and give the variable a sensible name and path.

More precisely, you define your output directory (say 'bin') as a linked folder, then you set that directory as the official output one of your project.

Comment: +1 linked folders are cool. I would recommend using them in conjunction with a Variable though to help maintain platform independence

Comment: VonC, Where is stored the mapping between the linked folder name and the real location ? I can't find it in the workspace nor in the project folder.

Comment: @Gilles: Hi Gilles, that is one weird sametime ;) I just defined one linked folder and see its definition (including the real path) in the `.project` file.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but it really s*ucks ! It really should belong to the workspace and be seat-specific !

Comment: @GillesPhilippart How would you guarantee that both you and I would define the same variable for the same purpose? After all, people typically don't share workspaces, just projects. It seems you're looking for the functionality typically provided by environment variables.