# Eclipse project folder

Tags: javascript, eclipse

I have the eclipse setup working pretty well for the java files in my code. But now I want to integrated the JS files also, leaving other XSLs/CSS files. Can I do that?
One is adding all the folders and then manually delete the unwanted ones, but Is there some clean way of doing that?

-Prtcl

Comment: Just completed my answer, with the "linked folder" trick which avoids copying anything in the workspace while allowing you to see this new resource (and to filter it)

Answer (score 1):

You can

- reference the JS folder in your workspace (*without actually copying it*): see **[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833)**.
- then try adding a filter (in the package explorer, in the upper right corner of the view, there is a little down arrow, with a Tool tip saying "view menu": [Java Element Filters](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-java-element-filters.htm))

[image: Filters]

If you do not want to view any xsl/css file, try to hide then to the "Name filter patterns" list

[image: Java Element Filters]

Comment: But it would copy the JS files to the Workspace location, I want the current JS files to be there itslef, and only use Eclipse to view and Edit those.