# Install folder hierarchy to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I am kind of new to the Eclipse IDE. I have a hierarchy of folders `C:\...\org\xmlvm\iphone` that contains a lot of java files. How can I use them in Eclipse via `import org.xmlvs.iphone;`?
UPDATE:
I found a .project and a .classpath file. Does that help? **I also found a .jar file.** Do I drop that in plugins or feature?

Comment: The .project file is an Eclipse project descriptor.  You could try using the Import Wizard (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-70.htm) to import the whole project.  The .jar file doesn't go in your eclipse -- you will want to set it up in your build path (http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm if it's not in the .classpath file already).

The help under the Eclipse help menu has everything I'm linking.  It is your friend.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a working Java project with a source folder?  If so, copy the `\org\xmlvm\iphone` into the source folder so the tree looks like `[source folder]\org\xmlvm\iphone`.  If you do not have an existing Java project, read the Eclipse docs for the [New Java Project Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-wizard-java-project.htm) and follow those instructions to create a project.  Then copy your files in per the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can add in your current Java project a **[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833)** pointing to that new directory.
Since you can have several source folder, simply declare that new directory as a source folder, and you are done.