# Include path of php.ini ignored by Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt, php, include-path

I have a PHP script to run. If I run it from the command line, it works fine (include path is set correctly).

If I want to run it inside Eclipse (Run as script), then the PHP include path of my php.ini is **replaced** by Eclipse, with all the libraries I've added to the project.

I've configured my PHP executable in Eclipse. I've set the correct PHP executable file, and I selected my php.ini file too (the right one, I've checked). But it is ignored...

Edit : this is an Eclipse bug :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/process_bug.cgi

Comment: I filled a bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=306401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug of Eclipse, 3 bugs have been filled about it but none of them got fixed.

No solution without modifying your PHP files.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/process_bug.cgi

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't manually re-adding the old paths using

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

in the first line of the script you're running work?

Comment: I guess it does, but I don't want to do that. The php.ini is here for that ^^ (and most of all this is a shared project, I can't)

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the current php include path as a **[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833)** within your project, in order to reference that linked directory in the PHP include path?

[alt text http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/include_path_properties.png](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/include_path_properties.png)

That way, even if your path is replaced, it will be replaced by:

- your path
- all the other librairies

Comment: Yes I guess this would be the fallback solution, but it bothers me that I (and my team) spent time configuring the php.ini, and that we should re-add it to Eclipse for each project (about 10). With the php.ini, it's done once. Eclipse sucks on that particular point or what ?

Comment: @Matthieu: true, but once added, it won't change, and the launched session will preserve that path. Not ideal but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse for PHP Cli Applications

1) Click on Project Properties

2) Click on Include Path

3) Add external folder and/or Source and/or Libraries

After doing such I was able able to run my programs. If I didn't do the above I was having to use the function

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "c:\PHP\PEAR"); etc...

For PHP Web applications I wasn't having issue because I put my include_path var in the Apache2 vhosts file along with my configuration.