# Eclipse CDT: Import source / header files into my new project, without duplicating them

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, workspace

Im sure there is a very simple solution for this.

I have a bunch of .cpp / .h files from a project, say in directory `~/files`

On the other hand, I want to create a c++ project using eclipse to work on those files, so I put my workspace on `~/wherever`. Then I create a c++ project: `~/wherever/project`, and include the source files (located in `/~files`).

The problem i'm having is that files are now duplicated in `~/wherever/project`, and I would like to avoid that, specially so I know which copy of the file to commit.

Is this possible? Im sure it is, but cant get it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

- creating the project directly above the `~/files` (which is not very clean, given the location of the sources in your home dir)
- using a [linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833)
- [importing existing sources in your project](http://carbidehelp.nokia.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/getting_started/cdt_w_existing_code.htm): details all the options (when your sources are also managed by a VCS like CVS, or when your sources are not managed)

Answer (score 3):

Create a file or folder in your project as per normal (choose File->New->Folder), give it a name, and click on the Advanced button. This reveals a file-choose field where you can browse for the resource you want to "virtually" include in the project. Click Okay and the file/folder you named is now linked outside of the project.