# Eclipse won't save new files in the original project folder

Tags: eclipse, version-control, workspace

I created a new project from an ant file that was in a folder outside of the Eclipse workspace, under version control. If I change a file that was already part of the project, it gets updated in its original location. **BUT**, when I create a new folder, it gets created outside of the original project folder, inside the Eclipse workspace, outside of version control. How do I make it save new files where the old ones are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.project` and `.classpath` files are *within* the eclipse workspace, you should define a **[linked folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833)** to reference and/or create files in directories outside your workspace.

Comment: The option "link to folder in the file system" doesn't seem to exist when creating source folders. Do you know what to do in that case?

Comment: @obvio171: create the linked folder first. Then right-click on it: the "Build Path" section of the contextual menu should propose: "Use as Source Folder".