# .project and .classpath files are missing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have a project where there are a no of applications built as separate Java projects.
These have been sent over by someone and somehow the `.project` and the `.classpath` files have not been copied.

So when I try to import it into eclipse it gives me an error:"`No project found`".
Is there any way to generate the missing files?

Comment: Not sure if this method was available when this question was posted, but Eclipse will make these files for you, at least for simple cases.  Added an answer for that.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the reason why you can not Import your project into Eclipse workstation is that you do not have `.project` and `.classpath` file.

Now that you know why this happens, so all we need to do is to create `.project` and `.classpath` file inside the project file. Here is how you do it:

First, create `.classpath` file:

1. Create a new txt file and name it `.classpath`.
2. Copy and paste following code and save it:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
    </classpath>
   ```

Then, create `.project` file:

1. Create a new txt file and name it .`project`
2. Copy paste following code:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <projectDescription>
    <name>HereIsTheProjectName</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
    </projectDescription>
   ```
3. You have to change the name field to your project name. You can do this in line 3 by changing `HereIsTheProjectName` to your own project name and then saving it.

Answer (score 7):

I've better solution for this issue, only for **MAVEN** users. To resolve it follow below steps.

1. GO inside your project `D:\workspace\project\`.
   2.Open command Line prompt and run this command : mvn eclipse:eclipse

Definitely, Your issue will gone.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot import them as project if .project and .classpath are missing. You can create a new Java project and copy the source files into it.

Answer (score 6):

### Let Eclipse Create the Files

Eclipse will make these files for you, but the way to make it do so is not very intuitive.

1. In Eclipse, make sure the project is not currently showing up in the **Project Explorer** or **Package Explorer**. If it is, right-click it and click the **Delete** button - **and make sure the "Delete from Disk" option is unchecked before you hit "Ok"!!!**
2. Select **File / New / Java Project**
3. Uncheck **Use Default Location**, then Click "Browse" and find the folder it is located in.
4. Click "Next" for more options, or just "Finish".

Eclipse will import the project and automatically create the default `.project` and `.classpath` files for you.  With the one case I tried, with source in the default src/main/java folder, I could build and run fine at this point.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Java Build Path help page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm):

- either you create project in the parent directories of the sources (in which case you add an existing subdirectory as your sources)
- or [you create an empty project in your Eclipse workspace](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#firstjava_project), and use the "link" feature

> Creates a new folder that links to an location outside of the workspace

That being said, you will still have to re-create the correct classpath yourself.

Comment: I tried the link feature but there the name of the packages changes and it is too tedious to change it all over again..instead i made empty projects and copied the folders..thanks

Comment: @swati: the link feature wouldn't change the name of your packages. i t would allow to declare an external directory as part of your project, and make that directory a 'src' one, to be compiled. But the directories in it (representing your packages) would be unchanged. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833 for more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have need to do anything. Just copy these two files from another projects and paste into that project directory where you getting issue.

Answer (score 0):

In **VS Code** it solved by just right-click on the *src* (the folder which contains all java files) folder and select the **" Add folder to Java source path"** option. If it didn't' worked, then try to remove it first by selecting **"remove the folder from Java source path"** (this will not result in any data loss) and then adding it again.

**Restart** once when done. **Hope it works for you in Eclipse too.**

[image]