# Hybris extension .project file

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have taken custom hybris extension folder from git and it does not contains any .project file. Will eclipse autogenerate this file while import or I need to make a new one?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880050/90513

If the Git project / repository is what your team is using, it's probably better to ask your team mate to push the .project file.