# ScalaTest in Java Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scalatest

I'm fairly new with ScalaTest, and now that I've got it running with Maven, of course I'd like to have it working well in Eclipse as well. My project is a Java project, but I want to improve my Scala skills by writing the tests with ScalaTest.

I understood it so that I should right-click on my project, say "Configure" and "Add Scala Nature". Doing that, however, makes Eclipse try to compile all my Java files with scalac, giving me a lot of "Scala Problem" entries in the problem list. Of course, not having the Scala nature gives me a lot of "Java Problem" entries in my project for all of my Scala files. How can I add the Scala nature only to src/test/scala?

Cheers

Nik

Comment: I think I have an eclipse project which contains a mixture of java and scala files and works just fine ... I might have, and when using maven you should anyway have src/java/main and src/scala/main folders.

Comment: When you have mixed Java/Scala, scalac _must_ be used on both `.java` and `.scala` files, to resolve dependencies, and then javac is run to actually compile the `.java`, with the target directory in the classpath, so it can find the files compiles by scalac. The thing is, scalac running on `.java` files shouldn't cause problems.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for letting me know. Curiously it did, I thought this was because it tried compiling them as scala files, but if it's meant to do this and should go well, I'll enable this again and perhaps open a thread on the errors it gives me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the simplest solution (in your context, i.e. classic Java project, without M2Eclipse and a Maven project) would be to have **two separate projects**:

- one with only the Java Nature
- one with the scala nature for tst.

Since you can [link a directory in your second project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse/1470833#1470833), you don't have to move the sources of the tests(`src/test/scala`) from your existing file set.
You only have to exclude `src/test/scala` from any compilation in the first (Java only) project.

Comment: That is indeed a simple solution I had not thought of. :-) I assumed I should be able to mix Java and Scala. I'll give this a whirl and report back :-)