# setting external output folder in eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am using `eclipse indigo`, trying to customize its output folder to be outside the project (actually, to copy output into `tomcat` installation).
I understand there are 2 possible solutions (none of them worked for me)

1. configure eclipse project output folder as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470827/external-output-folder-in-eclipse). But I did not find how to enter `linked folder` in output folder.
2. probably a smarter way - configuring `tomcat eclipse plugin` (I'm using [sysdeo plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html)). It did not work either: I can start tomcat from eclipse, but nothing is copied to tomcat installation.

thank for any tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the linked folder first (`right click on project > New > Folder > Advanced`)and then set the output folder to the linked folder in `project properties > Java Build Path > Source > Default output folder`.

Comment: thanks, if for example I define a linked folder "tomcat_output", what should I write in default output folder? If I write "tomcat_output", eclipse is looking for it under my project.

Comment: If you click the Browse button Eclipse will let you choose a folder. You just have to choose the linked folder. Output to the linked folder then will go to the actual folder on filesystem.

Comment: thank you! it worked at last! My prolbem was that I created a linked folder from another menu in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do some WebApp development in Eclipse? If so i would check out the WTP tools for Eclipse. It will allow you to run a Tomcat instance within Eclipse and handle the publishing of projects to it:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ